# Issue accessing an object key in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently doing a coding challenge and I am having trouble accessing the dna key for my new method (compareDNA) I keep getting an error and I am not sure how to fix this. `

```
// Returns a random DNA base
const returnRandBase = () => {
    const dnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G'];
    return dnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
};

// Returns a random single stand of DNA containing 15 bases
const mockUpStrand = () => {
    const newStrand = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        newStrand.push(returnRandBase());
    }
    return newStrand;
};


const pAequorFactory = (specimenNum, dna) => {
    return {
        specimenNum: specimenNum,
        dna: dna,
        mutate() {
            let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dna.length);
            let selectedDna = dna[randomIndex];
            console.log(`The original DNA base is ${dna[randomIndex]} at index ${randomIndex}`)
            let random = returnRandBase();
            if (random != selectedDna) { //This will ensure that the random base is NOT equal to the selectedDNA
                this.dna.splice(randomIndex, 1, random) //Changes the dna at the selected index, deletes 1 and replaces with random
            } else {
                console.log('Duplicate DNA found... generating new DNA.')
            }
            return dna;

        },
        compareDNA(pAequorObj) {
            let count = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.dna.length; i++) {
                if (this.dna[i] === pAequorObj.dna[i]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked other students solutions online and they have used the same method as I have, however, their solution works fine? Am I missing something silly here? Thanks.

This is the error I get:

```
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dna')
    at compareDNA (/Users/shibazhussain/Desktop/Code cademy projs/mystery-organism-starter/main.js:37:42)
    at <anonymous> (/Users/shibazhussain/Desktop/Code cademy projs/mystery-organism-starter/main.js:51:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:28:49)
```

Comment: @Pointy sorry new to stackoverflow, just added it now thanks

Comment: So how is this code used? Nothing you posted shows how the objects returned from that "pAequorFactory" function are used.

Comment: @Pointy so the compareDNA is supposed to compare the original dna that was passed in as an argument with the mutated DNA

Comment: Yes, right, and the error means that `this` or `pAequorObj`  is `undefined`, so that implies that the way that `compareDNA` is being called `this` is not being bound or the parameter is not passed. However, nobody can tell you why that is because how `compareDNA()` is called is a mystery.

Comment: More likely `pAequorObj` is undefined. Maybe you're not passing an argument when you call `something.compareDNA()`

Comment: @Barmar yea, one or the other, but either is possible.

Comment: @Pointy It takes some work to make `this` undefined. If you call it as an ordinary function, it will be the global object.

Comment: Somewhere you are calling `first.compareDNA()` instead of passing the second object to compare to?  Or you are passing the second object but it’s undefined?  We can’t see that code.

Comment: post your code where you use your functions. otherwise it's unclear what happens. btw you can step debug your code yourself and find the problem